# Non-zero smooth functions vanishing on a Cantor set

Tags: real-analysis

It is easy to give examples of continuous functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R_+\cup\{0\}$ non-zero but vanishing on a Cantor set (ex: [Can Cantor set be the zero set of a continuous function?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/24034/can-cantor-set-be-the-zero-set-of-a-continuous-function)). It is clearly non-true for analytic functions. My question is:

1. Are there uniformly continuous non-zero functions vanishing on a Cantor set?
2. Are there α-Hölder continuous non-zero functions vanishing on a Cantor set?
3. Are there continuously differentiable non-zero functions vanishing on a Cantor set?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A Cantor set $C\subset[0,1]$ is closed, and that is all we need.
Therefore $f(x)=d(x,C)$ (distance from $x$ to $C$) vanishes on and only on $C$.
It is also Lipschitz-continuous.

For your third question, you can take $g(x)=f(x)^2$.
This is $C^1$ apart from peaks in the middle points of the intervals of the complement of $C$.
You can easily smooth the function near these points, since you are well away from $C$.

Choosing a higher power gives you any $C^k$ smoothness you want.
But you can also get $C^\infty$.
Let $\phi:\mathbb R\to[0,\infty)$ be a smooth function vanishing on $(-\infty,0]$ and set  $g(x)=\phi(f(x))$ and mollify the tips.

Conclusion: The answer to all three questions is yes.

**Edit:**
It is not entirely clear what you mean by constructing by hand.
This is as close as I can come to making an explicit function if the Cantor set is not specified.
(I also noted that the distance was also used in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/24041/55893) to the OP's linked question. But it was not concerned with regularity.)

Comment: Thanks! I need to think a bit about your answer for the third question.

Answer (score 14):

By a theorem of Whitney, for any closed subset $C$ in $\mathbb R^n$ there exists a nonnegative $C^\infty$-function $f$ on $\mathbb R^n$ which vanishes exactly at $C$.
This also holds on any smooth manifold. I tried to find the exact reference, but I could not find it just now. Maybe, this result is hidden in:

- Whitney, Hassler: Analytic extensions of differentiable functions defined in closed sets,
  Trans. AMS 36 (1934), 63--89.

Comment: For a precise statement, see my answer.

Answer (score 11):

It's not hard to construct such a function explicitly.  Let $$\psi(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-1/(1-x^2)}, & -1 < x < 1 \\ 0, & \text{else} \end{cases}$$
so that $\psi$ is $C^\infty$ and is nonzero precisely on $(-1,1)$.  In the usual middle-thirds construction of the Cantor set, let $C_n$ be the centers of the intervals removed at step $n$ (there are $2^{n-1}$ of them and they have width $3^{-n}$; computing these points explicitly is left as an exercise for the reader with nothing better to do).  Then let
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{y \in C_n} \frac{1}{n!} \psi(2 \cdot 3^n(x-y)).$$
It should be easy to verify that the sum converges uniformly with all its derivatives, so $f$ is also $C^\infty$, and by construction we have made it strictly positive precisely on the removed intervals, i.e. the complement of the Cantor set.

Comment: $f(x)=\exp(-1/d^2(x))$ works for a general closed set $C\subset [0,1]$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: I'm sure you're right, though maybe it takes a bit of work to see that it is $C^\infty$.

Comment: On second thoughts, this version is actually not $C^{\infty}$ at the midpoint of a gap of $C$, but that's easy to fix (I need a smooth modification near that midpoint).

Answer (score 6):

This answer is to provide a precise statement for a result mentioned by Peter Michor.

> **Theorem (Calderón-Zygmund).**  If $F\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is closed, then there is a function $f$ such that
>
> - $c_1(n)d(x,F)\leq f(x)\leq c_2(n)d(x,F)$, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$,
> - $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n\setminus F)$ and  $$ \left|\frac{\partial^\alpha f}{\partial x^\alpha}(x)\right|\leq
>    c_3(n,\alpha) d(x,F)^{1-|\alpha|} \quad \text{for all multiindices
>    $\alpha$.} $$

This result says that there is a smooth regularization of a distance function. Originally it was proved in:

**A.P.Calderón, A.Zygmund,** *A. Local properties of solutions of elliptic partial differential equations.* Studia Math. 20 1961 171–225.

You can also find this result in

**E.M. Stein,** *Singular integrals and differentiability properties of functions.* Princeton Mathematical Series, No. 30 Princeton University Press, Princeton, N.J. 1970 (Theorem 2 in Chapter VI.2).