# A result attributed to Whitney

Tags: reference-request, real-analysis

One of the basic results of real analysis says that any closed subset of a smooth ($C^\infty$) manifold $M$ is the set of zeros of some map $\lambda\in C^\infty(M;[0,1])$. This result (or some equivalent variations of it) is usually attributed to Hassler Whitney.

*Question:* **exactly where** (title of Whitney's paper and page) is this stated?

Comment: Check http://mathoverflow.net/questions/179445/non-zero-smooth-functions-vanishing-on-a-cantor-set

Comment: @Pietro: following your link, Peter Michor says:" Maybe, this result is hidden in Whitney, Hassler: Analytic extensions of differentiable functions defined in closed sets, Trans. AMS 36 (1934), 63--89." But where?

Comment: I don't have Whitney's paper in front of me right now, but IIRC the extension operator constructed by Whitney when applied to the zero function (defined on a closed set $F$) has the property that the constructed function is comparable to the distance function from $F$. Do you need something else?

Comment: This is actually a very good elementary exercise. See Robert Israel's answer for $\mathbb R^n$, and glue by partition of unity: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/791248/every-closed-subset-e-subseteq-mathbbrn-is-the-zero-point-set-of-a-smooth. Whitney was concerned with much more subtle issues.

Comment: If you really like using Whitney's theorem, here is how (I will only do the case $M=\mathbb R^n$ here): Whitney proves that there is a function $f$ that vanishes on the given closed set $A$ and is analytic elsewhere. Then $f^2$ have the same property. Since zeros of analytic maps do not accumulate, they are isolated in the complement of $A$. Add a bump function to $f^2$ near every zero. This gives the desired function that vanishes precisely on $A$.

Answer (score 2):

[Analytic extensions of differentiable functions defined in closed sets](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1934-036-01/S0002-9947-1934-1501735-3/home.html)

see this [discussion](http://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Whitney_extension_theorem)

and this related [MSE question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48746/existence-of-non-constant-continuous-functions-with-infinitely-many-zeros) (first answer and comments)

Comment: where in that paper is it found or how do you get it from the stated results?

Answer (score 2):

According to **J.-C. Tougeron**, page 73 (Théorème 2.2) of *Idéaux de fonctions différentiables*, Ergebnisse, Band 71, Whitney's paper is

> Analytic extensions of differentiable functions defined in closed sets. *Trans. Amer. Math. Soc.* **36** (1934), pp 63-89.

Actually, Whitney's Theorem is stronger in two ways. On the one hand, every $C^m$-function $F:K\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ ($K$ the closed set) can be matched at order $m$ by a $C^m$-function $W(F):M\rightarrow{\mathbb R}$ which is $C^\infty$ away from $K$. On the other hand, the operator $W$ can be chosen linear and continuous (for the $C^m$-norms).