# On Cantor sets every map is $C^{\infty}$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis

For a fixed Cantor set $K\subset [0,1]$ and a continuous function $g:[0,1]\to \mathbb R.$ Is it always possible to find a $C^{\infty}$ map $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$ such that $g$ and $f$ coincide in $K?$

The case $g=0$ (the constant function $0$) is covered in [Non-zero smooth functions vanishing on a Cantor set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179445/non-zero-smooth-functions-vanishing-on-a-cantor-set).

Suppose for example that $K$ is the middle third Cantor set.

Comment: In this question do you want the function $g$ to have any smoothness or continuity properties?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem

Comment: What if your function $g$ is discontinuous on the Cantor set?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's see.  $1/3 \in K$ is a limit point from the left of points in $K$.  So try
$$
g(x) = \left|x - \frac{1}{3}\right|^{1/2}
$$
No function $f$ that agrees with $g$ on $K$ can have a finite derivative at $1/3$.