# Set of zeros of a real function of class $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis, gn.general-topology

Let $a < b$ two real numbers and let $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ a $C^1$ function. Moreover, we consider the set
$$
X := \{ x \in [a,b]\mid f(x) = 0 \}.
$$
Is it the number of **connected components** of $X$, at maximum, countable?

Comment: Looks like $X$ can be an arbitrary closed subset of $[a,b]$: just define $f(x) = (m(x)M(x))^2$, where $m(x) = x - \sup (X \cap [a, x])$ and $M(x) = \inf (X \cap [x,b]) - x$.

Comment: e.g. you can easily fill the holes of the Cantor set with small positive functions, to obtain a smooth function.

Comment: Historical note: it is an old and celebrated result of Whitney that any closed subset of a smooth manifold is the zero set of an infinitely differentiable function.

Comment: See also the questions https://mathoverflow.net/questions/196167/a-result-attributed-to-whitney or https://mathoverflow.net/questions/179445/non-zero-smooth-functions-vanishing-on-a-cantor-set

Answer (score 5):

As Mateusz Kwaśnicki pointed out in the comments:

> Looks like $$ can be an arbitrary closed subset of $[a,b]$: just define $f()=(()())^2$, where $()=−\sup(∩[,])$ and $()=\inf(∩[,])−$.

This takes the simpler function $f(x) = \inf \{ |x-y| | y \in X\}$ and fixes the points of non-differentiability (at the boundary of $X$ and at the midpoint of each open interval between two points of $X$).

We can even make it $C^{\infty}$, by taking $f(x) = e^{ - \frac{1}{m(x)M(x)}}$ for $x\notin X$.

We can take $X$ to be a Cantor set, which has uncountably many connected components (every point is its own connected component).

(Note that the complement of $X$ is open, and thus has countably many connected components, since each one contains a rational number.)